# Transistors to switch 12V 2A

Tags: arduino, switches, npn, 12v, pnp

I need to switch some power to a device, so I was wondering, if this will work OK, or do I need to add some other stuff to protect it, or make it work correctly.

I ran some simulations, on CircuitLab, and according to them this should work, but I would like, the opinion of other professionals.

> VCC = 12V (2A)
>
> YELLOW_IN, WHITE_IN = 0-5V, 40mA (PWM from Arduino)
>
> YELLOW, WHITE = VCC

I should also probably put a resistor between the Collector of Q1 and Base of T1.

This schematic is pretty straight forward, when you put 5V to YELLOW_IN it will act as a switch and then the YELLOW will be connected to VCC which is 12V.

Do you see any problems with this schematic or design?

[image: Schematic 1]

As for this schematic, it acts the same as the other one, except for one more case, I need to be able to supply ~0.4V to WHITE when WHITE_IN is 0.4V, and when WHITE_IN is 5V, it will bridge VCC with WHITE.

But in that case what happens with the voltage/current coming from WHITE_IN.

Do I need to build that part of the circuit differently ?

[image: Schematic 2]

**Edit 1: I've modified the schematics according to the suggestions, is this sufficient now.**

[image: Schematic 1]
[image: Schematic 2]

Comment: as a side note, not having read the question much yet, please follow the guidelines for drawing better schematics, which don't make us turn our heads and fart to make sense of it..

Comment: "I should also probably put a resistor between the Collector of Q1 and Base of T1." No, because R3 in your first schematic is already current-limiting into the base of T1, and R2 limits the current "out" of the base of T1.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do with D1 and R4 in the first diagrams, and in the second diagram explain what D3 is trying to do? And again, the D4 and R10 combination on the second diagram. They do not look logical/I don't see what you are trying to do there.

Comment: The diodes are there just in case there is current feed back, as the lines are attached to a small motor. There is no speed control.

Comment: Shouldn't the collector be connected to GND with a resistor on a PNP transistor?

Comment: Well the PNP transistor connects to GND through the load, usually. A motor is just a resistor and inductor in series, really. Make sure the motor has a clamping diode too, to  clamp it back to VCC. Your series diode will get in the way of that, however.. Go have a look at "half bridge" designs on the high-side (you are making a high side power switch for a motor). Also consider making the PNP transistor as a P-Channel MOSFET instead. Especially because it's doing 2A.

Comment: With the second schematic, there needs to be 0.4V, whenever the motor is not active. So should I just remove the diodes then? And I'm not actually controlling the motor, there is a switch before the motor, I just need to supply it with 12V (~2A), for it to activate.

Comment: 0.4V seen where?

Comment: On the schematic, where it says WHITE, if you set the WHITE_IN to >1V, it will trigger the transistors and then VCC will be directly connected to WHITE, but when it's not connected it needs to supply 0.4V

Comment: I just set WHITE_IN to 0.4V and then WHITE has 0.4V, because it's not enough to trigger the NPN transistor.

Comment: why is White-In going to 0.4V in the first place? And if you provide 0.4V, is that for sensing, or is there an actual load? Your schematic shows the input signal White-In being 0.4V, through a 10K resistor, and then into what I hope is a schottky diode with 0.3->0.4V turn on voltage. I'd go for 0.3V if you can, for that one.

Comment: There is a sensing component, it needs to supply ~0.4V, and from what I measured there is almost no load there.

WHITE_IN is connected to DIGITAL PWM PIN on the ARDUINO

Comment: Are you low-pass filtering the PWM to give a DC 0.4V, or you just need the average to be 0.4V via PWM (a % of 5V). I guess the 10K and 1UF resistor-cap pretty much does that hehe

Comment: Doesn't have to be correct, it needs to be anywhere between 0.2 - 0.4, so what I just set it to 0.4V, and it's around 0.35V which is sufficient for me.

Comment: Rpelacing 2n3904 with 2n2222 yes, it will work I tested that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your circuit looks OK, but it won't switch 2 Amps.

At 2A the TIP42 has typical DC current gain <=50 at 2A, so you need to feed *at least* 40mA into its Base. In your circuit Q3 cannot deliver this much, because R11 is limiting its Emitter current to about 9mA.

You should reduce the value of R11 to 100 Ohms or less. This will also increase Q3's Base current and R9 could drop several volts, so you should reduce the value of R9 to about 1k, and increase the value of C3 to about 10uF.

When switched on the 2N3904 will dissipate about 0.3W (7V x 0.04A) so it could get quite hot. You can reduce this heating by putting a resistor between the Collector of Q3 and Base of T3. A 100 Ohm resistor would drop 4V at 40mA, taking half the heat away from Q3.

Comment: Would you recommend I replace 2N3904 it with a different transistor then, and if so with which one?
Is there a different approach to do this?

Comment: I was planning to add a heatsink to the TIP42, or should I replace this one with a different one.

Comment: Should I replace the TIP42 with a MOSFET then?
What if I want to switch up to 5A

Comment: The TIP42 should work with the changes I suggested, but a suitably rated MOSFET (eg. IRF4905) would be more efficient.

Comment: What about the 2N3904, should I maybe replace it with 2N2222 ?

Comment: Should I just replace this with an N-Channel MOSFET like IRLR034A with an LTC115 to drive the MOSFET ?
Which circuit will be more efficient

Comment: Should I just remove the diodes in this case ? With the MOSFET, are they actually necessary?

Comment: If the diodes were necessary before then you still need them. I can't find any specs for LTC115. What is it?

Comment: Actually I missed a number it's LTC1155

Comment: LTC1155 would work well with an N-Channel FET, so long as you only want to turn the motor fully on and off (no PWM speed control).

Comment: like I said above, there is no need for speed control, it is just a switch to fully on or off.

Comment: I decided to go with LTC1155, and it works perfectly, thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 3):

This is simple, simulates nicely, and should work just fine.

[image]

R1 is the 2 ampere load, 10 millihenries is a WAG as to the motor's inductance, and I just semi-randomly picked  the FDS6576 out of the LTspice library; almost any P channel MOSFET will work there. Likewise, there's nothing holy about the 2N2222.

Here's a link to the [LTspice circuit list](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qlnexhczi1w2bu4/12V%202A%20switch.asc?dl=0) if you want to play with the circuit.

Comment: I ran simulation on the top circuit too, it simulated nicely, and there wasn't any issues. Do you see any issues with the edited circuits ?

Comment: @ilijamt I don't see the need for [on their schematics] C1, D1, R2, or R4, and R3 should be in the 100 ohm ballpark.

Comment: what about the second circuit, any recommendations on that ?

Comment: @ilijamt: Gimme a break, OK? I post a silk purse for consideration and you ask me how to turn your sows' ears into equivalents. To what end?

Comment: no need to be like that, just say no.

Comment: @ilijamt: I'm not an infinite sink, and I don't consider 0 rep much of a reward for extending a substantial helping hand.

Comment: Then say that if I want your help, I need to pay you and it's simpler.

Comment: And also I don't see any difference between the circuit I posted and the one you put, the difference is you removed a capacitor and a resistor.

Comment: @ilijamt: How can you not see a difference and then define the difference you don't see?